# Python: Converting string to floats, reading floats into 2D array, if/then, reordering of rows?

Tags: python, arrays, string

Let me start by saying that I know nothing about Python, but I am trying to learn(mostly through struggling it seems). I've looked around this site and tried to cobble together code to do what I need it to, but I keep running into problems. Firstly, I need to convert a file of 2 columns and 512 rows of strings to floats then put them in a 512x2 array. I check the first column (all rows) for negative values. If negative, add 512. Then I need to reorder the rows in numerical order and write/save the new array.

On to my first problem, converting to floats and putting the floats into an array. I have this code, which I made from others' questions:

`with open("binfixtest.composite") as f:
  f_values = map(lambda l: l.strip().split('   '), f)
  print f_values
  newarray = [map(float, v) for v in f_values]`

Original format of file:

`-91.  0.444253325
-90.  0.883581936
-89. -0.0912338793`

New format of f_values:
`['-91.  0.444253325'], ['-90.  0.883581936'], ['-89. -0.0912338793']`

I'm getting the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./binfix.py", line 10, in <module>
    newarray = [map(float, v) for v in f_values]
 ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -91.  0.444253325`

which I can't seem to fix. If I don't convert to float, when I try to add 512.0 to negative rows it gives me the error `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects`

Any help is most definitely appreciated as I am completely clueless here.

Comment: you are spliting on 3 spaces, but the number of spaces is variable. Just use `.split()`, it should be fine

Comment: Please clarify when you say "_reorder the rows in numerical order_". Do you mean by the first or second item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you anticipate having to do tasks like this now and then, I have some suggestions.

Something that will make your life a lot easier is to start learning to use `numpy` arrays instead of trying to use your own arrays (made up of lists of lists).

For this problem, you can use `numpy` like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.loadtxt('binfixtest.composite')
>>> data
array([[-91.    ,   0.44425332],
   [-90.        ,   0.88358194],
   [-89.        ,  -0.09123388]])
```

That's it. Done. Your data is now in a `numpy` array full of floats.

This works because by default, the [`numpy.loadtxt` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) reads line-breaks as row delimiters, and white spaces (including spaces and tabs) as column delimiters, and numbers as floats. There are also a lot of other options for customizing how `numpy` reads your file if you need them.

### Viewing your `numpy` array

To access row zero, do this:

```
>>> data[0]
array([-91.        ,   0.44425332])
```

To access a value at address `0,0`, do this:

```
>>> data[0,0]
-91.0
```

To access column zero, do this (the first colon means "all of the rows"):

```
>>> data[:,0]
array([-91., -90., -89.])
```

To access a row/column range, do this:

```
>>> data[1:, :2]
array([[-90.        ,   0.88358194],
       [-89.        ,  -0.09123388]])
```

The above means "all of the rows start at position 1, and all of the columns until and not including position 2". You can also do thing like `1:3`, which would get a total of two rows or columns (3-1=2) starting with position 1.

### Changing your `numpy` array

To change just a single value, do this:

```
>>> data[0,0] = 1
>>> data[0,0]
1.0
```

Note that the value we changed at `0,0` has been stored as a float, even though you assigned to an int. This is because a `numpy` array has ONE data type, and anything you put in that array will try to be converted to that data type:

```
>>> data.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

If you want to add 512 to a value at a specific address in the array, you can do this:

```
>>> data[0,0] = data[0,0] + 512
>>> data[0,0]
421.0
```

If you want to add 512 to the entire first column, you can do this:

```
>>> data[:,0] = data[:,0] + 512
>>> data
array([[  4.21000000e+02,   4.44253325e-01],
       [  4.22000000e+02,   8.83581936e-01],
       [  4.23000000e+02,  -9.12338793e-02]])
```

### Useful manipulations for your `numpy` array

If you want to do a comparison on an array (or a part of one), do that like this (it will return a new array):

```
>>> data<0
array([[ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

One way to get only the values in the array that are less than zero is the following (there are other ways):

```
>>> data*(data<0)
array([[-91.        ,   0.        ],
       [-90.        ,   0.        ],
       [-89.        ,  -0.09123388]])
```

This works because in `numpy`, `True` values act like 1, and `False` values act like `0`.

And finally, if you want to add 512 to the entire first column only if the value is negative, you can put all of those together and do this:

```
>>> data[:,0] = (data[:,0]+512)*(data[:,0]<0)
>>> data
array([[  4.21000000e+02,   4.44253325e-01],
       [  4.22000000e+02,   8.83581936e-01],
       [  4.23000000e+02,  -9.12338793e-02]])
```

### Save your array to a new file

If you wish to save the array to a new file, you can use the [`numpy.savetxt` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
>>> np.savetxt('output.txt', data, fmt = '%.8f', delimiter = '    ', newline = '\n')
```

The `fmt = '%.8f'` argument specifies how the float values should be printed (in this case, it will print with 8 decimal places). Consult [this part of the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

### First Part:

@njzk2 is exactly right. Simply removing the literal spaces to change from `l.strip().split('   ')` to `l.strip().split()` will correct the error, and you will see the following output for f_values:

> [['-91.', '0.444253325'], ['-90.', '0.883581936'], ['-89.', '-0.0912338793']]

And the output for newarray shows float values rather than strings:

> [[-91.0, 0.444253325], [-90.0, 0.883581936], [-89.0, -0.0912338793]]

### Second Part:

For the second part of the question "*if negative, add 512*", a simple loop would be clear and simple, and I'm a big believer in clear, readable code.

For example the following is simple and straightforward:

`for items in newarray:
    if items[0] < 0:
        items[0] += 512.00`

When we `print newarray` after the loop, we see the following:

> [[421.0, 0.444253325], [422.0, 0.883581936], [423.0, -0.0912338793]]

Comment: AH! I can't believe it was such a simple fix. So frustrating. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, I'm now trying to work on the if/then statement that adds 512 to any negative elements in the first column. I have: `if newarray[:][0] < 0:
        newarray[:][0] += 512.00` And it doesn't seem to be changing anything.